# How long will this battery power this LED strip?

Tags: led, batteries

I'm a novice when it comes to electronics and when researching this its blown my mind. I'm trying to figure out how long I can power 2 meters of [this LED strip](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Flexible-Lights-Daylight-Waterproof-Strips/dp/B00HSF66JO/ref=sr_1_6?ie=UTF8&qid=1448469213&sr=8-6&keywords=waterproof%20led%20strip) for using [this battery](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Rechargeable-Li-ion-Battery-4800mAh-Charger/dp/B00BWW4DGC/ref=sr_1_10?ie=UTF8&qid=1448471002&sr=8-10&keywords=12v%20battery)?

## Details:

### LED Strip:

- Voltage: 12V
- Total wattage of 2 meters: 9.6W

### Battery:

- Voltage: 12V
- Capacity: 4800mAh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At 12V and 9.6W the strips would consume 0.8A of current.

Divide that current into the battery capacity. 4.8Ah / 0.8A = 6 hours.

This is a very rough calculation, it's probably less than this. Real testing would be needed to verify this.

Comment: Great answer.  If the LED or battery is from a no-name supplier, the stats provided may have been exagerated, especially the battery.  I have found that most batteries coming from overseas suppliers that aren't name brand often have a much lower capacity than advertised!  Otherwise expect 6 hours.